# AttributeError: 'LabelPowerset' object has no attribute 'classes_'?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikit-multilearn

When I try to use LabelPowerset in scikit-multilearn, the code runs with GrieSearchCV with an error

```
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import LabelPowerset
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, hamming_loss
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
X, Y = make_multilabel_classification()
classifier = LabelPowerset(classifier=RandomForestClassifier())
parameters = {
'classifier__n_estimators': [10, 50, 100],
'classifier__max_depth': [None, 5, 10]
}
scorer = make_scorer(hamming_loss, greater_is_better=False)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(classifier, parameters, scoring=scorer, cv=5)
grid_search.fit(X, Y)
```

The above code reports an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zhangkai/.conda/envs/classifier/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 813, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "/home/zhangkai/.conda/envs/classifier/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 266, in __call__
    return self._score(partial(_cached_call, None), estimator, X, y_true, **_kwargs)
  File "/home/zhangkai/.conda/envs/classifier/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 353, in _score
    y_pred = method_caller(estimator, "predict", X)
  File "/home/zhangkai/.conda/envs/classifier/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 86, in _cached_call
    result, _ = _get_response_values(
  File "/home/zhangkai/.conda/envs/classifier/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_response.py", line 74, in _get_response_values
    classes = estimator.classes_
AttributeError: 'LabelPowerset' object has no attribute 'classes
```

I tried the example code given on the official website(http://scikit.ml/api/skmultilearn.problem_transform.lp.html#skmultilearn.problem_transform.LabelPowerset) and still reported the same error.

How to solve this problem?